# How do I center 2 authors with a title in the middle below

Tags: author

```
I tried the following
\author{
  X, Y
\and
Y, X 
\and \\ 
 firstname.lastname@uni-name.tld
}
```

But I get
[image]

But what I am really trying to get is the following:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: More precisely, different document classes handle authors differently.